# flexslider display images outside the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, flexslider

I am using flexslider(7.x-2.0-alpha3) on drupal 7.

The slider would appear in the front page and is working perfectly in chrome,safari and IE(> 8).
In firefox images are displayed on the right of the slider (The slider appears blank and the images are shown next to it).

I am using the latest version of Firefox (34.0.5), and I got the same issue with the previous versions.

One last thing, when I clear the cache, the slider works normally once (then restart failing after a refresh).

Does any one has this or can help ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you provide a link so that I can have a look?

Comment: Yes,Only Firefox doesnt work :
http://94.23.201.198/amdh-paris/